# Trying to add sums of random integers, VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to sum up all of the random integer values over 500 and then present them in a text box, however it is not working and whenever I run the code, it sums to zero.  This is inside of a user form using VBA. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim r As Double, c As Double, rand As Double, y As Double, x As Double, i As Double
    r = TextBox1.Value
    c = TextBox2.Value
    rand = TextBox3.Value
    Rnd [5]
    i = 0
        For x = 1 To r
            For y = 1 To c
                Cells(x, y).Value = Int(Rnd * rand)
                If (ActiveCell.Value >= 500) Then
                    i = i + ActiveCell.Value
                Else ' do nothing
                End If
            Next y
        Next x
        Cells(r + 1, c).Value = "SUM"
        Cells(r + 1, c + 1).Value = i
        MsgBox (i)
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know much about VBA, but could

```
Cells(x, y).Value = Int(Rnd * rand)
If (ActiveCell.Value >= 500) Then
```

.. be referring to different cells?

Comment: You are absolutely correct.  I replaced all of the **ActiveCell.Values** with **Cells(x,y).Value** and it worked!  Thank you for solving for solving this mystery of ages!

Comment: Sweet! I'm glad that helped :)